# javascript unexpected result in a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following code is Javascript for node.js. When I run it, console prints undefined, I don't know why. I expected it prints 'toto'.
Could you let me know why I don't get my expected result but undefined and how could I get my expected result printed ?

```
var Obj = function() {};

Obj.prototype.content = undefined;

Obj.prototype.showContent = function() {
    console.log(this.content);
}

Obj.prototype.init = function(callback) {
    this.content = 'toto';
    callback();
}

var myObj = new Obj();
myObj.init(myObj.showContent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you pass in a function like that, it loses it's `this` context. You need to bind the function to its parent object.

```
myObj.init(myObj.showContent.bind(myObj));
```

The way you have it written, `this` inside `showContent` will refer to the module scope instead of `myObj`.

Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/aOWBWO).